# Get Vimeo thumbnails for private videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a list of Vimeo private video urls (`https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234567890`), which I'd like to display as thumbnails on my page.
I can't find a working way to do it.

Any solutions based on `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/{id}` are long dead.

And something like this `https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/1234567890.jpg` would return the wrong image.

Is there a way to get an image thumbnail url based on video id without authorization ?

**UPDATE**

In my case, I manged to get the `thumbnail_url` by querying

`GET https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://player.vimeo.com/video/{id}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

oEmbed can be used to get a video's thumbnail links, depending on the video's [privacy settings](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview).

First off, oEmbed will only return metadata when the video has **embed privacy** set to **"Embed Anywhere"** or **"Only on site I choose"**. A video with its embed privacy to "Embed Nowhere" will return 403.

Videos with these viewing privacy settings will return "full" metadata (including thumbnail links):

- Anyone
- Only people with the private link (must use the complete video url)
- Hide this video from vimeo.com

Videos with these viewing privacy settings will only return the embed code:

- Only people I follow
- Only people I choose
- Only people with a password

oEmbed documentation can be found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since I don't have access to the account, I was unable to check our privacy settings and what exactly those setting hide. You explanation cleared things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for getting the Meta Data from Vimeo, with private videos.  You can see the solution here:

[VIMEO not consistently returning video title, duration or thumbnail url : REMOTE HEADER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920454/vimeo-not-consistently-returning-video-title-duration-or-thumbnail-url-remote/70921339#70921339)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Official PHP Library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php), this code worked for me..

```
require "path_to_library"
use Vimeo\Vimeo;
$video_id = "";
$vimeo_client_id = "";
$vimeo_client_secret = "";
$vimeo_access_token = "";
$client = new Vimeo($vimeo_client_id, $vimeo_client_secret, $vimeo_access_token);
$response = $client->request("/videos/$video_id/pictures/");
echo $response['body']['data'][0]['sizes'][count($response['body']['data'][0]['sizes'])-1]['link_with_play_button'];
```

This returns the largest thumbnail size, with the play button.